# Использование RadioButtons в matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, radiobutton

Разбираю пример работы `RadioButtons` в *matplotlib*.

Вот простой пример:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import RadioButtons


x   =[80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105]
s0 = [30, 22.5, 15, 7.5, 0, -7.5]
s1 = [29, 21.5, 14, 6.5, -1, -8.5]
s2 = [31, 23.5, 16, 8.5, 1, -6.5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
L0, = ax.plot(x, s0, lw=2, color='red')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.3)

rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.7, 0.15, 0.15], facecolor='yellow')
radio = RadioButtons(rax, ('1-я', '2-я', '3-я'))

def hzfunc(label):
    hzdict = {'1-я': s0, '2-я': s1, '3-я': s2}
    ydata = hzdict[label]
    L0.set_ydata(ydata)
    plt.draw()
    
radio.on_clicked(hzfunc)

plt.show()
```

В данном примере, при переключении `RadioButtons` всегда строится один график. Необходимо чтобы при переключении построилось два графика сразу.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать. Спасибо!

Comment: `Необходимо чтобы при переключении построилось 2 графика сразу` - какие два графика?

Comment: MaxU - любые графики из данных. Тут важно количество.

Comment: Если не хотите чтобы графики стирались не используйте `set_ydata` на одни и те же `axes`

Comment: @ClickName - при запуске строится один график. При выборе "2-я" первый график стирается и строиться другой график. Так же и с "3-я". Мне хочется, чтоб при выборе, например, "2-я" строился не один график, а например, 2 других.

Comment: @MaxU - любые графики из данных. Тут важно количество

Comment: Тогда сделай L1 и для него проделывай все те же вещи, что и для L0

Comment: @ClickName - если не затруднит, то чуть подробней, пожалуйста...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я *вот так* переписал вашу программу. Ничего красивого она не строит, зато изменив код очевидным способом вы сможете построить сколько угодно каких вам нужно графиков нажатием на соответствующие кнопки.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.widgets import RadioButtons

x   =[80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105]

s0 = [30, 22.5, 15, 7.5, 0, -7.5]

s1 = [29, 21.5, 14, 6.5, -1, -8.5]

s2 = [31, 23.5, 16, 8.5, 1, -6.5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

L0, = ax.plot(x, s0, lw=2, color='red')


plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.3)



rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.7, 0.15, 0.15], facecolor='yellow')

radio = RadioButtons(rax, ('1-я', '2-я', '3-я'))

def f_s0(ax, x):
    ax.plot(x,s0)

def f_s1(ax, x):
    ax.plot(x,s1)
    ax.plot([1,100],[100,1],'ro')

def f_s2(ax, x):
    ax.plot(x,s2)
    

def hzfunc(label):
    ax.cla()
    hzdict = {'1-я': f_s0, '2-я': f_s1, '3-я': f_s2}
    
    hzdict[label](ax, x)
    
    
radio.on_clicked(hzfunc)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import RadioButtons


x = [80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105]
s0 = [30, 22.5, 15, 7.5, 0, -7.5]
s1 = [0, 21.5, 4, 6.5, -1, -8.5]
s2 = [1, 23.5, 16, 8.5, 1, 6.5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2)                                    # +++  2
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.3)

rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.7, 0.15, 0.15], facecolor='yellow')
radio = RadioButtons(rax, ('1-я', '2-я', '3-я'))

def hzfunc(label):
    ax[1].clear()
    if label == "2-я":
        ax[1].plot(x, s1, lw=2, color='blue')
        ax[1].set_title("2-я")
    elif label == "3-я": 
        ax[1].plot(x, s2, lw=2, color='green')
        ax[1].set_title("3-я")
    elif label == "1-я":
        ax[1].axis('off')
    plt.draw()
    
radio.on_clicked(hzfunc)

ax[0].plot(x, s0, lw=2, color='red')
ax[0].set_title("1-я")
ax[1].axis('off')

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: огромное спасибо за помощь! Немного не то. Я хочу, чтоб на одном axes при выборе, например, "2-я" рисовалось сразу два графика одновременно!

Comment: огромное спасибо за помощь! Но в своём вопросе я немного подразумевал другое. Я хотел, чтобы на одном Axes при выборе, например, "2-я" строилось сразу два графики.

Comment: @AleksandrАPashayev я не понимаю что вы хотите, после вашего уточнения в комментариях.